# Get process id (pid) for running python (jupyter-kernel)

Tags: python, process, ipython

I've started a jupyter kernel form emacs-jupyter. I'd like to get the process id for the python process associated with the buffer so that I can attach a debugger to it. How can I do this in elisp?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```el
(process-id (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))
```

should do it. You can replace the call to `current-buffer` by some other means of identifying the buffer of interest, and you should probably check that the result of `get-buffer-process` is not nil.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was my first try, but `get-buffer-process` returns nil. I don't understand because there is clearly a python process associated with the buffer (jupyter kernel).

Comment: If `get-buffer-process` returns `nil`, then there is no process associated with the buffer (if you kill the buffer with `C-x k`, it asks for confirmation if there is a process associated with the buffer - that's what happens e.g. when you start a shell with `M-x shell` and then try to kill the `*shell*` buffer - does it do that if you try to kill the jupyter-kernel buffer?) You might have to delve a bit deeper into what `emacs-jupyter` does to figure out what process is associated with what buffer.

Comment: It suggests `Jupyter REPL (*jupyter-repl[python 3.9.4]*<2>) still connected.  Kill it? (y or n)` when I kill the buffer. So I would think there is a process associated with the buffer. I did browse the emacs-jupyter code a bit, but unfortunately I am not an elisp expert.

Comment: Since the error mentions `jupyter-repl` and `get-buffer-process` returns `nil`, I checked and indeed, the error originates from that source file: https://github.com/nnicandro/emacs-jupyter/blob/master/jupyter-repl.el#L1373 You're correct, there must be a process that Emacs is communicating with.  Looking through the same file shows that the REPL start process uses `jupyter-kernel-process-manager`, of which there is also a source file.  That's where you can find the Emacs process handle.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: This line looks promising: https://github.com/nnicandro/emacs-jupyter/blob/1f0612eb936d36abab0f27b09cca691e81fc6e74/jupyter-kernel-process-manager.el#L85 I'd throw a `message` statement in there or jump in a debugger to see what the kernel object looks like.  (Of course, you could track down its definition and see if there's a slot (i.e. attribute) for what you want).  There is also something called `jupyter--debug` referenced in the code; that might have the info you need or give a hint at how to get it.